# Prevent double submission with prevent window event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following function to prevent double submissions:

```
$("#form").submit(function () {  
    var form = $(this);  
    form.find("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled")  
    form.find("input[type=submit]").attr("value", "Processing");  
  });
```

It works fine, but then I have the following code which triggers an alert to avoid accidentally leaving the page:

```
function goodbye(e) {
     if(!e) e = window.event;
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = '¿DO YOU REALLY WANT TO LEAVE THIS PAGE?'; //This is displayed on the dialog

//e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
```

The problem is if the user clicks submit and the realizes he didnt want to leave the page and clicks on stay on this page instead, the submit button is still disabled.

How could I re-enable it upon clicking stay on this page?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to block a form submit that way in the first place? User will be confused

Comment: Form processing has a delay period, so I'm trying to avoid double submissions.

Comment: That part is understandable, but using `onbeforeunload` with a form is not. Should have a flag that prevents `onbeforeunload` returning once form is submitted

Comment: Right. But in this particular case the user needs to confirm form submission in order to prevent mistakes. That is why I need the submit button to be active again in case they cancel the confirmation.

Comment: How are you going to prevent double submissions if you enable the button again?

Comment: It need it to be disabled ONLY upon confirmation of onbeforeunload function

Comment: If the user doesnt confirm he wants to leave the page, it should stay enabled.

Comment: Why not handle the confirmation of form submission in the submit handler?  This isn't really a good use for `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: I also need to prevent accidentally leaving the page by clicking on a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The button problem

You want to disable and enable the submit button so you know you going to touch the same kind of function and object twice, it is better to make advantage out of this in a function

```
function disableSubmit(form, enabled){
    var submit = form.find("input[type=submit]"),
        dataVar = enabled !== true ? "processing-message" : "send-message",
        message = submit.data(dataVar);

    submit.prop('disabled', (enabled !== true) );
    submit.val(message);
}
```

I could make it even more generic for using it on each form. But the message in the button will display whatever you put in the data-attribute.

#### Cancel Submit

There is a problem with cancellation of an onbeforeunload event; there is **no** callback for it. The solution I came with is using a timeout. Since you don't know if the person canceled or not, I think 2 seconds is enough for the page to submit. 
You have to have 2 seconds patient to get the submit button enabled again. But you can adjust it all you want of course

```
if (e.stopPropagation) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        disableSubmit(formObject, true);
    }, 2000);
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

[The JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Drifter/aadfneu0/)